# SQL Server's isNumeric() equivalent in amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

- I'm using amazon redshift as my data warehouse
- I have a field (field1)of type string.  Some of the strings start with four numbers and others with letters:

'test alpha'
'1382 test beta'

- I want to filter out rows where the string does not start with four numbers
- Looking at the redshift documentation, I don't believe isnumber or isnumeric are functions.  It seems that the 'like' function is the best possibility.
- I tried

  where left(field1, 4) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

this did not work and from the link below seems like redshift may not support that:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=439850

is there an error in the 'where' clause?  if not and that clause isn't supported in redshift, is there a way to filter?  I was thinking of using cast

```
cast(left(field1,4) as integer)
```

and then passing over the row if it generated an error, but not sure how to do this in amazon redshift.  or is there some other proxy for the isnumeric filter.

thanks

Comment: your example doesn't work on PostgreSQL. ILIKE doesn't support regular expressions. Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2 so maybe you can use SIMILAR operator http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO- REGEXP because SIMILAR is keyword, maybe ... some like SELECT substring('1234 xxx' FROM 1 FOR 4) similar to '[\d]{4}';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that redshift doesn't support any of the following:

```
where left(field1,4) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
where left(field1,4) ~ '^[0-9]{4}'
where left(field1,4) like '^[0-9]{4}'
```

what does seem to work is:

```
where left(field1,4) between 0 and 9999
```

this returns all rows that start with four numeric characters.

it seems that even though field1 is type string, the 'between' function interprets left(field1,4) as a single integer when the string characters are numeric (and does not give an error when they are not numeric).  I'll follow up if I find a problem.  For instance I don't deal with anything less than 1000, so I assume, but am not sure, that 0001 is interpreted as 1.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Take the following example:  `select count(*) from a where thing = '3081_xl7' and thing between 0 and 999999;`  This will return 1.  In this case, `thing` is a `varchar` column.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like:

```
where field1 ~ '^[0-9]{4}'
```

It will match any string, that starts with 4 digits.

Comment: thanks Igor and Pavel.  unfortunately, it doesn't look like the above works with redshift.  the following statement:

Comment: sorry, comment was cut off...thanks Igor and Pavel.  unfortunately, it doesn't look like the above works with redshift.   When I add the 'where field1 ~ '^[0-9]{4}'' clause into the statement, the statement returns: 'ERROR: Regular Expression Matching is not supported [SQL State=XX000] '.  If I try 'where field1 like '^[0-9]{4}'' it returns an empty table, but no error.  If I try 'where field1 like '$'' it returns all rows.  It seems redshift only supports 'like', but not the rest of the expression.  Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: if you want to take a closer look, this is the link to the redshift docs regarding 'like': <http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_patternmatching_condition_like.html>

Comment: Currently (October 16') this statement is working in Redshift queries

Answer (score 14):

Although long time has passed since this question was asked I have not found an adequate response. So I feel obliged to share my solution which works fine on my Redshift cluster today (March 2016).

The UDF function is:

```
create or replace function isnumeric (aval VARCHAR(20000))
  returns bool
IMMUTABLE 
as $$
    try:
       x = int(aval);
    except:
       return (1==2);
    else:
       return (1==1);
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Usage would be:

```
select isnumeric(mycolumn), * from mytable
    where isnumeric(mycolumn)=false
```

Comment: Should be top answer

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the code you are looking for the is the `similar to` function:

```
where left(field,4) similar to '[0-9]{4}'
```

[Redshift doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-similar-to.html)

Comment: This one worked well for me except you have to use apostrophes: where left(field,4) similar to '[0-9]{4}'

Answer (score 4):

Per Amazon, the posix style ~regex style expressions are slow...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions.html

Using their own `REGEXP_*` functions seems to be faster.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/String_functions_header.html

For checking just a true/false for integers I've been using the following with success.
`REGEXP_COUNT(my_field_to_check, '^[0-9]+$') > 0`

*this returns 1 if only numeric, 0 if anything else*

Answer (score 2):

```
where regexp_instr(field1,'^[0-9]{4}') = 0
```

will remove rows starting with 4 digits (the above regexp_instr will return 1 for the rows with field1 starting with 4 digits)

Answer (score 2):

We have tried the following and worked for most of our scenarios:

columnn ~ '^[-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,}$'

This will positive, negative, integer and float numbers.

Answer (score 1):

redshift should support similar to.

```
WHERE field1 SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{4}%'
```

This reads as where field1 starts with 4 characters in the range of 0-9, then anything else.