# Redshift (SQL): try convert to timestamp

Tags: sql, string, casting, timestamp, amazon-redshift

I have a column with timestamps as string, like so:

```
starttime             | attribute
2000-08-21T23:10:37Z  | X
```

Now I want to convert these strings to proper timestamps in AWS Redshift.
The following works for the row shown in the above example,

```
 CAST(starttime as timestamp)
```

but some rows are not in the correct format and hence throw an exception:

```
 error:  Invalid data
 code:      8001
 context:   Invalid format or data given:
```

Is there a way to use something similar to ***try_convert*** available in MS SQL server?
I have tried the following without much success:

```
case when starttime ~ '\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}Z' 
then cast(starttime as timestamp) else null end
```

But this regex expression does not work.. Also tried using [[:digit:]] instead of \d or \d, but nothing works..

To be clear: I know that some rows contain erroneous data so I am not worried about excluding them.

Comment: I would encourage you to load correct data-type to redshift either by changing the loading script so that any date operations performed with ease. 

Besides, try out Pythonic version Redshift UDFs to parse such conditions. Redshift UDFs approach creates SQL agnostic solution and scales well to support multiple date formats out of the box.

Comment: @kadalamittai thanks for your feedback, the UDFs look really promising and will use them soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed out a minor detail: change all the `\d`s to `\\d`. As per the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html):

> Amazon Redshift supports the following Perl-influenced operators in regular expressions. Escape the operator using two backslashes (‘\’).

I tried the following:

```
create temp table v (starttime varchar(255));
insert into v values ('2000-08-21T23:10:37Z'), ('ddd');

-- the next line doesn't work, as you yourself suggested.
select CAST(starttime as timestamp) from v;
-- the next line works.
select case when starttime ~ '\\d{1,4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}T\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}Z' then cast(starttime as timestamp) else null end from v;
```

Comment: Works, but was hoping there exists something similar to try_convert. I guess using a UDF functions is adaptable too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948323/sql-servers-isnumeric-equivalent-in-amazon-redshift (second answer)

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the T from the string and replace with a space you can cast

CAST(replace(starttime, 'T', ' ') as timestamp)