# Numerical values from string - SQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-cleaning

I am facing problems extracting the numerical values from the beginning or the end of a string. I was planning to use a SUBSTRING function (or RIGHT/LEFT) in order to isolate the two or three digit numbers from the beginning or the end of the string (I do not need to convert them into INT). But I have two issues:

- my column is a string
- not all of the strings have numbers at the beginning or at the end.

In order to solve the first issue I tried to use the function ISNUMERICAL (to understand where I have numerical values) but I got an error saying that does not exist in SQL Amazon Redshift. Then, I would like to get 0 in all the other inputs that do not have a number as first or last character. Below you can see how my column looks like and on the right (after the arrow) how I would like to get my output.

```
column_name | result
------------|-------
12aaaaaa    | 12
375aaaaa    | 375
98aaaaaa    | 98
aaaaaa89    | 89
aaaaaa34    | 34
aaaaa567    | 567
aaaaaa8a    | 0
aaaaaaaa    | 0
a7aaaaaa    | 0
```

Does anyone of you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You need to use the REGEXP_COUNT function to test for numeric. REGEXP_COUNT(input_value, '^[0-9]+$') > 0.  This answer has some useful information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948323/sql-servers-isnumeric-equivalent-in-amazon-redshift

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some common roots they are substantially different.

Comment: See above - it is CRITICAL that you choose whether this is a redshift or postgres question and edit accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for PostgreSQL:

Here is a variant that first splits the strings in parts and then selects the appropriate one:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p[1] <> ''
            THEN p[1]::integer
            WHEN p[array_upper(p, 1)] <> ''
            THEN p[array_upper(p, 1)]::integer
            ELSE 0
       END
FROM (SELECT regexp_split_to_array(string, '[^\d]+') AS p
      FROM strings) AS q;
```

This assumes that the table is called `strings` and the column `string`.

Comment: This may not be correct of the question is redshift as regexp_split_to_array is not supported - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html - waiting for OP to sort out the tags